How can I position a dialog next to specific page elements so that its placement remains consistent across different screen sizes?
I'm trying to position a dialog (e.g., a tooltip, dropdown, or modal) adjacent to a specific element on the page. The goal is to keep the dialog consistently positioned relative to the element, regardless of the screen size or resolution.
Currently, the dialog's position shifts when the screen size changes, which leads to misalignment or overlap with other elements. I need a solution that ensures the dialog stays anchored next to the target element without breaking the layout on different devices or when the screen is resized.
Question:
How can I position a dialog next to specific page elements in a way that its placement remains consistent across different screen sizes?
This is my code:
  void onActionButtonPressed() {
    showDialog(
      barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
      context: pageContext,
      builder: (context) => Align(
        alignment: const Alignment(0.52, -0.65),
        child: Container(
          constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 320, maxHeight: 235),
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 24, 24, 32),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: CustomColors.surface,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
              border: Border.all(
                width: 1,
                color: CustomColors.outline,
              )),
          child: const Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text("TEXT HERE"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }



In Flutter the concepts of tooltip, dropdown, or modal are very different from one another, which one do you want to use?

I want to use modal. @pcba-dev

You can combine CompositedTransformTarget with OverlayPortal

@Md.YeasinSheikh Can you please provide example how to do it?

You can use the Positioned widget in the Stack instead of relying on the Align widget with static alignment values.Here is the modified code
void onActionButtonPressed(BuildContext context) {
      RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
      Offset offset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
      Size size = renderBox.size;
    
      showDialog(
        barrierColor: Colors.transparent,
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              left: offset.dx,
              top: offset.dy + size.height, 
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Container(
                  constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 320, maxHeight: 235),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(24, 24, 24, 32),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: CustomColors.surface,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 1,
                      color: CustomColors.outline,
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: const Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text("TEXT HERE"),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }


Great solution, I used this with a slight refactor. I added fixed values for Positioned parameters, and now when I scale the screen to a bigger monitor it stays in position. Thank you, my friend.

You can use CompositedTransformTarget and CompositedTransformFollower or OverLayPortal for this. Here is an example
class _SpecificPositionedDialog extends StatefulWidget {
  const _SpecificPositionedDialog({super.key});

  @override
  State<_SpecificPositionedDialog> createState() => _SpecificPositionedDialogState();
}

class _SpecificPositionedDialogState extends State<_SpecificPositionedDialog> {
  final LayerLink layerLink = LayerLink();

  bool showLink = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        CompositedTransformTarget(
          link: layerLink,
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              showLink = !showLink;

              setState(() {});
            },
            child: const Text("Show"),
          ),
        ),
        if (showLink)
          CompositedTransformFollower(
            link: layerLink,
            showWhenUnlinked: false,
            targetAnchor: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            followerAnchor: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              width: 200,
              color: Colors.red.withOpacity(.2),
            ),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}


Thank you for your help, I will see if this solution is ok for my problem.
